# How do i use 3/4 username in laravel 6.* or later version?

Tags: laravel

I stored data in user table like "id, name, username, phone_no, employee_no, email, password and many more columns.
I want to log in as Username & Password, email & Password, phone_no & Password, employee_no & Password.

what is the methodology need for this?
currently, I'm using a username & Password as laravel default.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your authentication method, you might need to override the function that looks for the user. But if you're asking for the query, typically you would do something like this:

```
User::where(function($query) {
   $query->where('username', $accountIdentifier)
   ->orWhere('email', $accountIdentifier)
   ->orWhere('phone_number', $accountIdentifier)
   ->orWhere('employee_number', $accountIdentifier);
});
```

`$accountIdentifier` would correspond to the input of the user, which could be any of those parameters. It's also worth noting that I put it inside a sub-query because you might need to check for accounts that are active, or accounts that are verified.